# Trouble iterating through nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am having trouble adding a particular value to one of the entries in my dictionary. Instead of adding a value to one particular entry in my nested dictionary, the value is added to all entries in my dictionary . For example if I write

data_dict['2022-03-07']['POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE'] += 1

It will add entries an entry of 1 into [every_date]['POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE']

here is my code

```
import pandas
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

data_set = pandas.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Miles\Downloads\schedule_a-2024-03-02T09 13 57.csv")

data_dict = {}
contribution_dict = {"INDIVIDUAL":0,'ORGANIZATION':0,'POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE':0,'CANDIDATE':0,
                     'OTHER COMMITTEE':0, 'CAMPAIGN COMMITTEE':0  }

# a_list = ['INDIVIDUAL', 'ORGANIZATION', 'POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE', 'CANDIDATE', 'OTHER COMMITTEE',
#           'CAMPAIGN COMMITTEE']
list = []

for all_dates in range(len((data_set['contribution_receipt_date']))):
    contribution_date = data_set.at[all_dates, 'contribution_receipt_date'][:10]
    dummy = dt.date(int(contribution_date[:4]), int(contribution_date[5:7]), int(contribution_date[8:]))
    if dummy in list:
        pass
    else:
        list.append(dummy)

list.sort()
for all_values in range(len(list)):
    data_dict[str(list[all_values])] = contribution_dict


data_dict['2022-03-07']['POLITICAL ACTION COMMITTEE'] += 1

~~~
```

Comment: Note: don't use `range` and `len` when iterating.   E.g. `for i in range(len(lst)): print(lst[i])` vs. `for x in lst: print(x)` or if you need the index: `for i, x in enumerate(lst): ...`

Answer (score 1):

This is because dictionary is a mutable type in python.
In this fragment:

```
for all_values in range(len(list)):
    data_dict[str(list[all_values])] = contribution_dict
```

you are assigning the same contribution_dict dictionary (the same object, the same address in memory) to all data_dict keys.

The fastest fix would be to make a new dictionary in each loop iteration:

```
for all_values in range(len(list)):
    data_dict[str(list[all_values])] = contribution_dict.copy()
```